# Opening a new page on website exit

Tags: javascript

What I want is to have a new page or pop up to be activated when:

1. a visitor on my website closes the browser
2. a visitor on my website types another URL in his browser.

I have this JS, but it is activating a new website (www.newpage.com) also als for internal links. How can I disable this action for internal links?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var leaving = true;
function checkUrl(href) {
    leaving = (((href.indexOf("http://") > -1) || (href.indexOf("www.") > -1)) && (href.indexOf(window.location.host) == -1));

}
function pop() {
    if(leaving) window.open("http://www.newpage.com");
}
window.onunload = pop;
var e = documents.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++) e[i].onclick = "checkUrl(this.href)";
</script>
```

Comment: How about "no". Popups in general are annoying. There is no justifiable use for one when the user is trying to leave.

Comment: Whenever I get a pop-under window (usually equipped with some loud autoplay video), I want to slap the person responsible for it in the face.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable this action for internal links?

Use specific links with `id` instead of getting all the anchors based on tag name.

```
var e = documents.getElementById("anchorId");
e.onclick = "checkUrl(this.href)";
```

#### *Also,* Listens to the comments. POPUPs are the big NO is current web world

Opening a new window when a user is actually trying to leave??? This may have the tendency to the make the viewer angry and *never return on the site*. **BAD MOVE**